# Directory For C# Library Download

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to set up the MongoDB c# plugin on my computer. I use visual studio 2010 to code. Where should the extracted zip file be moved to? In the folder that I use for development or is their a specific file path for this type of library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NuGet package manager to download MongoDB C# driver. It will be placed under *packages* folder at solution root directory.

How to use NuGet: either *Manage NuGet packages...* option in context menu of project references to search driver online. Or simply type

> Install-Package mongocsharpdriver

In Package Manager Console (located under *TOOLS > Library Package Manager*). That will download latest stable version of driver to your solution and add assembly reference to project.

Answer (score 0):

You can put under any directory. Best practise is using NuGet. Otherwise you can put in a directory in the project folder. This way you will not lose your library when you need to reopen project after awhile.